# Python - KeyError(key) is raised but it shouldn't

Tags: python-3.x, configparser

Why this code raises error:

```
import configparser
import os


path = '/home/solus/Downloads/TestOnMe'
os.chdir(path)

config = configparser.ConfigParser()

config.read('extensions.ini')
extensions = config['Extensions']
```

But on contrary this code works flawlessly:

```
import configparser
import os


config = configparser.ConfigParser()

config.read('extensions.ini')
extensions = config['Extensions']
```

The error is following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/solus/Documents/Projects/Python/Learning Python from YT/Own/configurator/testtesttest.py", line 11, in <module>
    extensions = config['Extensions']
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 959, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'Extensions'
```

Content of extensions.ini:

```
[Extensions]
music = ['mp3', 'acc']
photos = ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png']
archives = ['rar', 'zip', 'tar', 'tar.bz', 'tar.gz']
documents = ['epub', 'pdf', 'doc']
```

Both Python file and .ini file are in the same directory.

Comment: do a `print(config)` after `config.read =...` to see if the key is part of the dictionary. It could be a typo. Also you can set a breakpoint there and have a look at all the variables created. cheers

Comment: When I run `print(conifg)` the result is `configparser.ConfigParser object at 0x7f46c56f8198`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is pretty easy. Look closely:

```
import configparser
import os


path = '/home/solus/Downloads/TestOnMe'
os.chdir(path)
```

With `os.chdir(path)` you changed your path to `'/home/solus/Downloads/TestOnMe'`. Since the path is changed Python tries to search for `extensions.ini` within *TestOnMe* directory. That why it raises an error. To correct this mistake you need to change order of your instructions.

```
import configparser
import os


config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('extensions.ini')

path = '/home/solus/Downloads/TestOnMe'
os.chdir(path)

extensions = config['Extensions']
```